# What is the best way in Vim to operate on relative ranges in visual mode?

Tags: vim, range

I often delete, yank, and paste using something like this:

```
:3,6y
```

Since Vim 7, I've switched to using relative line numbers. I find it's much easier to use relative line numbering with commands like `h,j,k,l` etc.

Since switching to relative line numbering, I find it difficult to operate on absolute ranges (eg. `:3,6y`). It takes me too long to determine what absolute line numbers I need to select since Vim is displaying relative line numbers.

What is the best/quickest way to use visual selection on a range if your setup is displaying relative line numbering? Naively, I'm looking for something like:

```
:-2,+8y 

(yank the lines from 2 lines above my current position to 
8 lines below my current position.)
```

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly you delete, yank and paste in visual mode by using something like this: `:v 3,6y`? I can't understand how this command relates to visual mode.

Comment: Opps, I did not intend for this question to be phrased for visual mode. I've edited it so that it should now be correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you try your naive thing?

`:-2,+8y` is equivalent to `:.-2,.+8y` and should do what you want.

Note that if you don't specify a number, `1` is assumed, so: `:,+y` means `.,.+1 y`: yank current and next line.

On `:help range` it is not well explained. The relevant parts are here:

```
Line numbers may be specified with:     *:range* *E14* *{address}*
    [...]
    .       the current line              *:.*
    [...]
Each may be followed (several times) by '+' or '-' and an optional number.
This number is added or subtracted from the preceding line number.  If the
number is omitted, 1 is used.
```

What the doc does not tell is that if the `+` r `-` is not preceded with anything, `.` is assumed.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for. I did not understand the use of the period from the docs and I was getting a `Backwards range given, OK to swap (y/n)` when using negative numbers.

Comment: To get to the right part of `:help`, you should add `:` before `range`.